# Form sending GET request to Flask when POST is expected

Tags: html, forms, post, flask, get

I have a form in my Flask template.

```
<form id="answer_form" action=http://127.0.0.1:5000/answer_doubt method="POST">
                Answer:<textarea rows='10' cols="100" form="answer_form" wrap="soft" name="answer"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ entry.content.id }}" name="id">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The method of the form is clearly declared POST but it is sending GET.

Therefore, I am unable to use request.form.
What should I do to solve this error. Am I making, like, a really obvious mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you verify that it is `GET` and not `POST`? Or do you just not see anything in `request.form`? (Also maybe quote around your action)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the full url from your action.

```
<form id="answer_form" action="/answer_doubt" method="POST">
                Answer:<textarea rows='10' cols="100" form="answer_form" wrap="soft" name="answer"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ entry.content.id }}" name="id">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "Your action has no quotations" - For the value given to the attribute in the question, they are not required. Even if they were, then that would break the `action` **but** the space before `method` would ensure that it **was** parsed as a new attribute.